# Unable to locate ros-hydro-desktop-full

Tags: ros, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, I followed the ros wiki.  I added the sources and the apt-key and they both show up with cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list and with sudo apt-key list.  But when i sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full or even sudo apt-cache search ros-hydro (or any disto), nothing shows up.  Im running on xubuntu with xfce on a chromebook if that help at all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90606/unable-to-locate-ros-hydro-desktop-full/) by [frodo0321](https://answers.ros.org/users/7731/frodo0321/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-10-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-14**:
Did you run `apt-get update`?

**Comment by [frodo0321](https://answers.ros.org/users/7731/frodo0321/) on 2013-10-14**:
By looking at other questions I figured someone would ask me that haha.  And yes, multiple times.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-14**:
What is the output of your apt-get update? Does it show packages.ros.org being downloaded? What version of Xubuntu are you using?

**Comment by [frodo0321](https://answers.ros.org/users/7731/frodo0321/) on 2013-10-15**:
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise Release.gpg
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise Release
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise/main armhf Packages
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main Translation-en
are all the ros packages.  and lsb_release -a outputs
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ahh, you are using armhf.  Not all packages are available for armhf, especially the desktop packages.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [frodo0321](https://answers.ros.org/users/7731/frodo0321/) on 2013-10-15**:
Is there any way around that?  Like compiling from source or something?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-15**:
Yeah, though a lot of the visualization libraries are not going to work well on embedded computers. http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source

**Comment by [frodo0321](https://answers.ros.org/users/7731/frodo0321/) on 2013-10-15**:
now it can't locate python-wstool... I can't win haha

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-15**:
It's available from pip.  Armhf is not an officially supported architecture, so there's going to be a little bit of extra work to get things working.

**Comment by [kristpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20419/kristpan/) on 2014-10-08**:
I am not using armhf but find the same problem.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-08**:
@kristpan: you should probably ask that as a new question rather than trying to reopen a year-old question.